# Laravel | Generate PDF file from Blade view. Data from relationship tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables Pages and Subpages in relationship one to many. In Subpages table I have page_id which is associated with the pages table id.

In my Page model I have:

```
 public function subpages(){
        return $this->hasMany(Subpage::class); 
 }
```

In PageController, function generatePDF:

```
    public function generatePDF(PageRepository $pageRepo, $id)
    {
        $page = $pageRepo->find($id);


        $title = $page->title;
        $subtitle = $page->subtitle;
        $description = $page->description;
        $subpage_title = $page->subpages()->title; /// HERE IS PROBLEM

        $data = [
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
            'subpage_title' => $subpage_title, 
        ];
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pages/page/' . $page->$id . '/myPDF', $data);

        return $pdf->download($title . '.pdf');
    }
```

How to display the assigned subpages?? I try in different ways, but I still get the error:

```
Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's `1-N` relationship how do you want to take single `title`? 
You could take all subpages, loop through them, and collect every `title` in an array.

F.E.

```
$subpage_titles = [];
foreach($page->subpages() as $subpage){
    $subpage_titles[] = $subpage->title;
}
```

Comment: I try to use your example but I still get an error: Array to string conversion

Comment: That's because `$subpage_titles` is an array :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
public function subPageData()
    {
        $array_string = [];
        foreach($this->subpages as $page){
            $array_string[] = $page->title;
            $array_string[] = $page->description;
        }
        return implode("\n",$array_string);
    }
```

This method returns:

Title 1

Description 1

Title 2

Description 2

...